# RewriteCond exclude folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

This works nicely, but I don't want the RewriteRule to trigger for the following folder and its subfolders.

```
www.site.co.uk/Content
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(content)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

or create a .htaccess in content directory and put

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Comment: That does not work. The following `http://www.site.co.uk/Content/Articles/84/icon.jpg` is still forwarded to index.php.

Comment: The `RewriteEngine off` worked. Thanks. I never would have thought of that.